# make svg file with polygons clickable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have to build an interactive map in JavaScript.
I read that d3.js can handle SVG images to add click functions to the polygons in the SVG.

Does anybody know how to add click functions to this SVG map ([link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Municipalities_in_Bavaria.svg))
The goal is to make the 1300+ municipalities in Bavaria clickable to add some information if somebody hover or click on the polygon.

If someone has a better idea to realize this, then that would of course also be fine

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach using vanilla js.

Assuming you can use the svg inline and have the data you want to display organized in a way similar to this:

```
const data = {
  municipality_name_one: { name: 'a', size: 1, population: 2, foo: 3 },
  municipality_name_two: { name: 'b', size: 2, population: 3, foo: 4 },
  municipality_name_n: { name: 'c', size: 3, population: 4, foo: 5 },
};
```

You could give the `polygon`s in that file an `id` or some `data-field` that points at the corresponding data and have an event-handler on the parent svg that displays that data when the `polygon` is clicked, like so:

```
svg.addEventListener('click', ({ target: { id } }) => {
  if (id in data) {
    const { name, size, population, foo } = data[id];
    alert(`${name} has size of ${size} and pop. of ${population}. ${foo}`);
  }
});
```

To show the data on hover, you would want to use a `mouseover` handler.
In both cases, you will want to also consider the event that should hide the data again. This should help you get started, tho.

Comment: Is there no possibility to make the data automatically clickable, since there are quite a lot of entries.

Comment: @Mo7art I don't think there is. Depending on your data you could possibly do it differently, but you do need a way to link the entries with the svg shapes. How else would the browser know what info to display?